# Select the first image from multiple images using JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `food`, `fav_food` and `food_image`. The `food` table has details about foods, `food_image` has multiple images for a single food and the
`fav_food` table has user's favorite food ids.

```
food:
f_id   |  description  

food_image
f_id   |   img_url  | rank

fav_food
user_id  |  f_id
```

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT food.f_id, 
       food.description, 
       img.minimgrank, 
       i.img_url AS profile_photo 
FROM   fav_food 
       INNER JOIN food 
               ON fav_food.f_id = food.f_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT f_id, 
                              Min(rank) AS minImgRank 
                       FROM   food_image 
                       GROUP  BY f_id) img 
                    ON img.f_id = food.f_id 
       JOIN food_image i 
         ON i.rank = img.minimgrank 
WHERE  fav_food.user_id = ?
```

Now I need a query that will show the favorite foods of user with description and  image. Although there is multiple images, I need to select a single image with minimum rank (Suppose rank- `1,2,3` the the image with rank `1` will be selected). So my question is how to write a faster query to achieve my goal?

Comment: Please add your sample code you tried.

Comment: The query i tried is added @MohammadMohabbati

Comment: There are different factor to your code run faster. For example indexes, tables structure, your code and hardware. However, in your code you can use `RANK()` window function instead sub query. It helps you to make your query faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you help with a full query? @MohammadMohabbati

Answer (score 1):

Consider joining the three tables and after that using a window function such as `min(rank)` to get the results.

```
select * 
from (
       select a.user_id
              ,b.img_url
              ,b.rank
              ,min(b.rank) over(order by b.rank asc) as rnk
       from fav_food a 
       join food_image b
       on a.f_id=b.f_id
       join food c
       on a.f_id=c.f_id
     )x 
where x.rank=x.rnk
```

Comment: Thanks @George Joseph for your answer. Now can you tell me what's wrong with the query i've tried :) ?

Comment: In the version you have. The join condition is missing the f_id comparison. Consider JOIN food_image i 
         ON i.rank = img.minimgrank AND i.f_id=IMG.f_id.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where a correlated subquery should have better performance:

```
SELECT f.f_id, f.description, 
       fi.rank, fi.img_url AS profile_photo 
FROM fav_food ff JOIN
     food f
     ON ff.f_id = f.f_id LEFT JOIN
     food_image fi 
     ON fi.f_id = f.f_id AND
        fi.rank = (SELECT MIN(fi2.rank) FROM food_image fi2 WHERE fi2.f_id = fi.f_id)
WHERE ff.user_id = ? ;
```

For performance, you want to be sure that you have an index on `food_image(f_id, rank)`, and `fav_food(user_id, f_id)`, as well as indexes on the primary keys.

Why is this faster and than the `GROUP BY` version?  First, indexes can be used for the correlated query, but probably won't be for the `JOIN` after the `GROUP BY`.

Second, the `GROUP BY` needs to process *all* the data in the images table.  This only needs to process the favorite foods for the given user.

Finally, `ROW_NUMBER()` is an option in MySQL 8+.  However, this is still likely to be as fast or faster than that solution (based on my experience with other databases).